# Heading element inside <li> element

Tags: xhtml

Is `<H#>` element inside HTML `<li>` element considered semantically correct?

Comment: Please note that you should be asking about "validity" - essentially whether h# inside li is *grammatically* correct. There's no way of telling whether your use of h# and li is *semantically* correct without seeing the content being marked up, and the context in which it is being used.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546327/headers-in-definition-terms-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many tools that no web developer should be without.  One of those tools is a good HTML Validator add-on for your browser.

Firefox HTML Validator Add-on:
http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/

Chrome HTML Validator add-on:
http://robertnyman.com/2010/04/07/html-validator-extension-for-google-chrome/

I especially like the one for Firefox.  If there is a validation error in your HTML, not only will it tell you, but it also tells you why it's bad and how to fix it.

To answer your question, I do believe h# are considered valid inside an <li> element.  But it may also depend on DOCTYPE as there are different rules for different HTML DOCTYPES.  However, with the validator you'll never need to ask a question like this again :)

Answer (score 5):

Yep. According to http://validator.w3.org/check anyway... it's a great tool.